# Pause news ticker on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a news ticker found on this jsfiddle but its not working as i want .the problems are :

1. as i increase the width and height of all the divs .It doesnt work properly the last divs get overlapped on first div of second turn of news.
2. the news divs inside main divs are not circular 1st news should be followed by the last .
3. it doesn't pause onmouseover.

**Here's the fiddle for this**
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/rNXs9/1/)

```
<script>
  window.verticalScroller = function ($elem) {
  var top = parseInt($elem.css('top'));
  var temp = - 1 * $('#verticalScroller > div').height();
  if (top < temp) {
    top = $('#verticalScroller').height()
    $elem.css('top', top);
  }
  $elem.animate({
    top: (parseInt(top) - 60)
  }, 600, function () {
    window.verticalScroller($(this))
  });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  var i = 0;
  $('#verticalScroller > div').each(function () {
    $(this).css('top', i);
    i += 60;
    window.verticalScroller($(this));
  });
});

</script>
```

I am applying this one beacause it doesn't require any jquery .If i use a ticker with jquery and plugins the previous jquery doesn't work even after using no confliction method. kindly help me out of this .

**UPDATE:**

```
<div id="verticalScroller">
<div style="position: relative;height:200px;width:352px;">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
<div style="position: relative;height:200px;width:352px;">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
<div style="position: relative;height:200px;width:352px;">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
<div style="position: relative;height:200px;width:352px;">4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
</div>
```

css update:

```
#verticalScroller {
position: absolute;
width:352px;
height: 380px;
border: 1px solid red;
overflow: hidden;
}
#verticalScroller > div {
position:absolute;
width:50px;
height:50px;
border: 1px solid blue;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a stop using conditions in following way:

```
window.verticalScroller = function ($elem) {
    if (window.stop == false) {
        var top = parseInt($elem.css("top"));
        var temp = -1 * $('#verticalScroller > div').height();
        if (top < temp) {
            top = $('#verticalScroller').height()
            $elem.css("top", top);
        }
        $elem.animate({
            top: (parseInt(top) - 60)
        }, 600, function () {
            window.verticalScroller($(this))
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.verticalScroller($elem);
        }, 600);
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    window.stop = false;
    var i = 0;
    $("#verticalScroller > div").each(function () {
        $(this).css("top", i);
        i += 60;
        window.verticalScroller($(this));
    });
    $("#verticalScroller").on('mouseenter', function () {
        window.stop = true;
    });
    $("#verticalScroller").on('mouseleave', function () {
        window.stop = false;
    });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNXs9/1279/)**

Comment: working good with mouse over but as i change width and height of all containers and main div the last div overlaps to first div . see my update i've changed width and height of divs its overlapping to one another

Comment: this mouseover is not working on my page , i am running it on localhost wamp server but its working on jsfiddle@Gaurav Kalyan